# Best Storyboard-Practice for App w/ Initial Setup Screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, storyboard

In creating an App, I want to achieve:

```
First Visit (if !setup):
1) SetupView [UINavigationController]
2) OverviewView [UINavigationController]

Second Visit (if setup):
1) OverviewView [UINavigationController]
```

I'm looking to use storyboards, but what is the best practice to use here? Should I

a) Create separate storyboards (one for setup, one for regular use) and change between those two

b) Have a single `storyboard`, with two separate `UINavigationControllers`, having `SetupView` as the initial and programmatically check `setup? yes/no` to forward to the `OverviewView`? If so, which transaction? I tried doing this, but the App crashes if I do a push segue to the new nav controller.

Looking forward to hearing from you guys!

Comment: No need to create separate storyboards. Go for option "b". Post your code how you push your ViewController and what error do you get ?

Comment: I would go for option b but vice versa. Per default the app starts in the overview and i would segue to setup only when required. Regardig the crash let's have a look at the relevant code. You must have made a mistake there as this should work in principle.

Comment: I think my problem was that I was pushing from Setup to Overview. I didn't want the Back-button, so I tried pushing to the Navigation Controller instead (which generated the error). But now, thanks to @HermannKlecker, I have Overview as my initial and prompt Setup as a modal. This should work without trouble, thanks.

Comment: Then present the setup modally if you don't want a back button.

Answer (score 0):

go with option B, you just need to make sure in your app delegate to perform a check on which controller to show. 
You can set in your Settings.plist a BOOL variable that show if the setup has already done or not. fetch that result from your settings plist and use it to call one or another view controller. ( if the BOOL hasSetup is TRUE ( you already have setted all up ) you won't even create the instance of the setup controller ).